# jsx display page variations under a condition of a boolean

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I was looking to display Parameters and Disconnect in my homepage if the states of the var userConnected is true and to display only Login and Register if the state of userConnected is false.

[image]

I would like to see the 2 first if user isn't connected and only the 2 others if user is connected.

I don't know how do this, it would be something like a variation page depending on a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole JSX structure is essentially just an expression, and you can introduce conditional parts of an expression with the ternary conditional operator.  In JSX that might look something like this:

```
<Parent>
  {
    someBoolean ?
      <Child1 /> :
      <Child2 />
  }
</Parent>
```

Of course, `<Child1 />` or `<Child2 />` can themselves be an entire tree of JSX elements, and can have further conditional expressions therein, etc.  (Or can just be `null` if you don't want to render anything for a given condition.)  But the structure is still the same.

Comment: Thanks ! It is possible to do this in a same page ? Like if I put a route to go to home page, I do like 2 versions of it.
<Route exact path="/">
          <Home {userConnected ? <Child1/> : <Child2/> />}
       </Route>

It is possible to display child 1 everytime and in some cases display child 1 AND child 2 ??

Comment: @Nabd: The syntax of your example doesn't look right, so that may be what isn't working for you.  But in general this same structure applies everywhere in the entire component hierarchy.  You can conditionally render whatever structure you like, based on any condition you like, and any time state updates that condition then a re-render will show the updated hierarchy.

Comment: The syntax it's because i'm using react-router-dom 5.2.0 and it have changes on news versions
Thank you for the aclarations.